# Searching for files with a .dcm extension in a particular drive c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, search, directory

I'm trying to search for files of extension .dcm, by entering either the filename or the content of the file. I am able to search in a directory, but when i try searching in a drive, I get an error that says missing directory or an assemble reference.

```
string startFolder = @"C:\";
// Take a snapshot of the file system.
System.IO.DriveInfo dir = new System.IO.DriveInfo(startFolder);

// This method assumes that the application has discovery permissions
// for all folders under the specified path.
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.
                                                               SearchOption.
                                                               AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Just want to point that since you are searching for `*.dcm` files you may change your `searchPattern` to be `"*.dcm"` instead of `"*.*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to search in drive like in folder it works:

```
    string startFolder = @"c:\";
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Hi,when i do that i get this error: Access to the path 'C:\System Volume Information' is denied.

Comment: Ok. in this case you should implement a recursive algorithm yourself and catch sequrity exception. Let me see if I find a code snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out immediatelly all the files with *.dcm extension

```
string startFolder = @"c:\";
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.dcm", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

After that use foreach loop to find either a file with the desired name or open the file for reading and search for the value inside the file.

Are *.dcm text-based files or binary files? If they are text-based files you could use regulare expression to figure out whether the search string exists or not.

EDIT: Here is the sample recursive function that does the job. It is a console application so adapt it for your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace FileSearcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static string searchValue = "Windows";
        static List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startFolder = @"C:\";
            DirectoryInfo diParent = new DirectoryInfo(startFolder);

            FindSearchValue(diParent);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", file.FullName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Recursive function that searches for a file that matches the criteria.
        /// If the file is not found, the current file is opened and it's contents is 
        /// scanned for search value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="diParent">Current parent folder being searched.</param>
        private static void FindSearchValue(DirectoryInfo diParent)
        {
            FileInfo[] foundFiles = diParent.GetFiles("*.doc");

            foreach (var file in foundFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);

                if (file.FullName.Contains(searchValue)) // There is a search string in a file name
                {
                    files.Add(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

                    if (fileContents.Contains(searchValue)) // Here you can use Regex.IsMatch(fileContents, searchValue)
                    {
                        files.Add(file);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var diChild in diParent.GetDirectories())
            {
                try
                {
                    FindSearchValue(diChild);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function uses try-catch block to intercept exceptions that might occur. For example, file not found or access denied. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,when i do that i get the same error: Access to the path 'C:\System Volume Information' is denied. .dcm are IMA files.

Comment: Have a look at my EDIT. Modify it as you see it fit. Change *.txt to *.dcm inside the recursive function. Optimize it if you want. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function to avoid exceptions:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    IEnumerable<string> result;
    try
    {
        result = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        result = new string[0];
    }

    IEnumerable<string> subDirectories;
    try
    {
        subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        subDirectories = new string[0];
    }

    foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> subFiles = GetFiles(subDirectory, pattern);
        result = result.Concat(subFiles); //This is LINQ concatenation
    }
    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    string startFolder = @"c:\";
    foreach (string fileName in GetFiles(startFolder, "*.chm"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Hi,when i do this, i get an error saying System.IO.Directory does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateDirectories'.When i checked up on this, it says i need .NET 4 version and i have .NET 3.0. what could i do next? thanks.

Comment: Try to use 'GetDirectories()' instead.